# Static context for some often needed Data? Best Practise?

Tags: php, oop, static, coding-style

I have written some Web Framework in PHP. I was been advised to do nothing in static Context. But i have some Question about this.

Imagine the following Class:

```
class Image extends HtmlControl {
    public $src;
    public $alt;
    function getDetailPath()
    {
        return 'Common/Image';
    }
}
```

It is nothing special. It is a Class to render an Image in Html. My Base Class has current following Implementation:

```
abstract class HtmlControl {
    private $template;

    abstract function getDetailPath();

    public function __construct(ViewInformation $viewInformation) {
        $this->template = 'foo/bar/' . $viewInformation->getEndpoint() . '/' . $this->getDetailPath() . '.php';
    }

    public function render() {
        $output = '';
        //Load template end fill $output
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Also nothing Special. It basicly will resolve the Endpoint Type (something like Frontend or Backend) to the corresponding template file, and provide the method render to get the output.

The Problem is, i need everytime for each part of a html controll to give the `$viewInformation` parameter.

```
$img = new Image($this->_info);
```

In my opinion something like this would be much nicer:

```
$img = new Image();
```

So i would have to save the State, which Endpoint should be used, in a static Context. Something like this (Note the `Request::getEndpoint()` Part):

```
abstract class HtmlControl {
    private $template;
    abstract function getDetailPath();

    public function render() {
        $template =  'foo/bar/' . Request::getEndpoint() . '/' . $this->getDetailPath() . '.php';
        $output = '';
        //Load template end fill $output
        return $output;
    }
}
```

My Question: Is it in this case okay, to have the endpoint in a static context? If not, could my current implementation improved?

Comment: Why not pass the context in when you do `->render()`? Also, I think if you're going into this kind of detail, perhaps you would want to rather use a `DOMDocument` :)

Comment: The bad thing about static stuff is essentially hidden dependencies; secondary to that are issues related to testing.

Comment: Thanks @Jack , this is a good point. I will change this. You gave me a small, but great answer. It helps me realy. Because i load "$img" in a "$container", my $container can handle this. Didn't the the forest because of the trees :)